Facebook login redirect_uri php
i'm working on an extension for OpenCart to bind social account to OpenCart Account i'm keep facing this issue:
Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri
is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

i'm sure that the redirect_uri is the same since i'm refrencing the same class variable in step 1 and step 2 of the Facebook login process but still got the same issue.
i had tested all solution suggested by people but none worked.
here's my code and a screen shot of "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs"



after changing redirectUriFb to
redirectUriFb = https://*******.com/index.php?route=extension%2Fmodule%2Fsocial_bind%2Ffcallback

it started working seems kind of problem with encoding mean while i used rawurlencode and urlencode
